# Android Studio not showing source set when adding new resource file

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

When I try to add a new resource file (ie. File>New>Android Resource File) "Source set: " is missing. Does anyone have any ideas why that could be?

Comment: Can you please explain your problem more? what type of resource file you are adding? and where are you trying to add it, under which directory? what is the error message exactly? can you share some screenshot if possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have enough rep to include a screen shot. It is the same for any resource file for any directory. I added some instructions to my question. I hope that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

I also had the same problem. I couldn't solve it. But you can still manually add a source set for different flavors.

In ur project view, right click on app >> New >> Folder >> Res Folder.
Then choose a specific flavor in "Target Source Set".

You can see the details here in the link https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html.

Android Studio will create a source set for you for that flavor.
Try to add whatever resource file you want manually there.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is by design -

When you add a new resource **file** by right clicking on the `res` folder, you cannot select a source set; but if you add a new resource **folder** first, you will be able to select a source set.

After that, just right click on the new source set and add new resource files.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug. File >  New > XML > Values (or Layout) Resource File does create a new resource file in the current build variant.

Answer (score 0):

if you want Source set to appear you have to add the new resource file in res folder not any other one like drawable or layout

Answer (score 0):

You can creat it from

> new >> folder >> Resfolder

Then change the `build flavor` from the `buildvariance` tap at the left and add the files you want by new at the `flavor folder`.

Answer (score 0):

As Moe Han answered you could refer to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html.

One thing you need to concern is that you need to choose one of the Build Variants before creating a source set directory you want to make. If not, Android studio couldn't recognize that source directory I think(no icon changes).